# jQuery function looping or not ending

Tags: jquery

My basic function here brings up a popup when you click on an image, and allows you to browse through a list of friends and swap the current picture on the page with one from the popup. The swap works fine, but my function seems to fire multiple times - I know this, because the d variable shows up in the console multiple times. On the first use, it shows up once. On the second, it shows up twice, etc.

I imagine it has something to do with the $('#friendlist li').click function inside of the main loop, and that it is either not "shutting down" once the picture gets replaced, or something to do with variable scope.

```
$('img[name=pop]').click(function(e) {
        //pop up
    var p = $(this);
    var position = p.position();
    var offset = p.offset();
    $('#friendlist').css("left", position.left + $(this).width() );
    $('#friendlist').css("top", 0);
    $('#friendlist').toggle();
    //console.log( this );
    //console.log( position.top + " " + offset.top + " " + e.pageY );       

        //listener for the friendslist, retrieves the uid of the friend chosen
    var pointer = $(this).attr("id");
    var c = 0;
    console.log( "before c: " + c );
    $('#friendlist li').click(function( ){
        var d = 0;
        console.log( "inner d: " + d );
        if( d < 1){
            pictureReplace( pointer , $(this).attr("id") ); //function that swaps the img
            $('#friendlist').hide();
            d++;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the basic HTML for the page:

```
<div id="main_page">

<div>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $friendList[0]['id']; ?>/picture" name="pop" id="friend1" />
    <?php echo $friendList[0]['name']; ?>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="img/<?php echo $friendList[1]['id']; ?>" name="pop"  id="friend2" />
    <?php echo $friendList[1]['name']; ?>
</div>

<div>
    <img src="img/<?php echo $fb_me['id']; ?>" />
    <?php echo $me['name']; ?>
</div>

<div>
        <img src="img/<?php echo $friendList[2]['id']; ?>" name="pop" id="friend3" />
        <?php echo $friendList[2]['name']; ?>
</div>

<?php //create the friends list for the search ?>
<div id="friendlist">
    <div>People</div>
    <input type="text" id="fsearch" name="fsearch" class="" />
    <ul id="friends_ul">
    <?php
        $li_num = 1;
        foreach($friendList as $key => $val){
    ?>
        <li id="li_id_<?php echo $li_num; ?>">
            <img src="img/<?php echo $val['id']; ?>" />       
            <label><?php echo $val['name']; ?></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenid" value="<?php echo $val['id']; ?>">
        </li>       
    <?php
        $li_num++;
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you click on an image, you are adding a new event handler to `$('#friendlist li')`.

I quick fix would be to [`unbind` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the existing handler before adding a new one:

```
$('#friendlist li').unbind('click').click(...
```

I would probably bind the handler only *once*, use a shared variable and [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) ( I don't really understand what your `c` and `d` variables are doing, so I removed them):

```
(function() {
    var pointer,
        $friendlist = $('#friendlist');


    $('img[name="pop"]').click(function() {
        //pop up
        var $p = $(this),
            position = $p.position(),
            offset = $p.offset();

        $friendlist.css({
            left: position.left + $p.width(),
            top: 0
        }).toggle();

        pointer = this.id;
    });

    $friendlist.delegate('li', 'click', function() {
        pictureReplace(pointer, this.id); //function that swaps the img
        $friendlist.hide();
    });

}());
```

Also note that `name` is [not a valid attribute for `image` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-1.html#htmlimageelement). I would use a class, so that you can select the elements with `$("img.pop")`.